# grails: assigning a domain class to another domain class

Tags: groovy, grails-2.0

I have a scenario where users are assigned to team.
Different ClientServices  are  allocated to different teams and
we need to assign user Of these teams to clientservice in RoundRobin fashion
I was trying to solve it as follows to get a map where team name and a list of ClientServiceInstance will be mapped so I can do further processing on it

```
def teamMap = [:]  
clientServicesList.each {clientServiceInstance->  
            if(teamMap[clientServiceInstance.ownerTeam] == null){  
                teamMap.putAt(clientServiceInstance.ownerTeam, new ArrayList().push(clientServiceInstance))  
            }else{  
                def tmpList = teamMap[clientServiceInstance.ownerTeam]  
                tmpList.push(clientServiceInstance)  
                teamMap[clientServiceInstance.ownerTeam] = tmpList  
            }  
        }    

but instead of pushing clientServiceInstance it pushes true.

Any idea?
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe another version would be:

```
def teamMap = clientServicesList.inject( [:].withDefault { [] } ) { map, instance ->
  map[ instance.ownerTeam ] << instance
  map
}
```

Comment: I knew you'd have something clever ;)

Answer (score 1):

`new ArrayList().push(clientServiceInstance)` returns `true`, which means you're putting that into your `teamMap` instead of what I assume should be a list? Instead you might want

```
teamMap.putAt(clientServiceInstance.ownerTeam, [clientServiceInstance])
```

By the way, your code is not very Groovy ;)

You could rewrite it as something like

```
def teamMap = [:]
clientServicesList.each { clientServiceInstance ->
    if (teamMap[clientServiceInstance.ownerTeam]) {
        teamMap[clientServiceInstance.ownerTeam] << clientServiceInstance
    } else {
        teamMap[clientServiceInstance.ownerTeam] = [clientServiceInstance]
    }
}
```

Although I'm sure there are even better ways to write that.